# Как сделать размер картинки: под размер контейнера если она больше, а если меньше то в оригинальном размере

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать размер картинки: 
под размер контейнера если она больше, а если меньше то в оригинальном размере

Comment: img { max-width: 100% }

Comment: и что вы будете делать, если картинка в ячейке таблицы, например?

Answer (score 2):

Если картинка внутри контейнера как `<img>`, то прописать ей свойства `object-fit: contain; width: 100%; height: 100%;`

Если картина как фон (`background-image`) контейнера, то прописать контейнеру свойство `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Тут важно указать, что `object-fit`, нормально работает если `img` задан `width || height`.. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6h9g42z/)

Comment: точно, спасибо. Подправил.

Answer (score 0):

Прописать `max-width` у изображения